# Export Room Database File and Send it to server using retrofit kotlin

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin, retrofit2

I want to export my database file and tehn send it to server using retrofit.
Challenges: Cannot find the request body type for db file in retrofit to send.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MultiPart` like below.

Convert you file to Multipart like

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, dbFile);
MultipartBody.Part bodyPart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", fileName, requestBody);
```

Then in your api interface

```
@Multipart
@POST("database-upload")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadBackup(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

Comment: I am haaving another issue now, I am copying that database and saving it in memory for sending later if no internet available.
But when I try to use new created db file to send to server, it gives uri as "content://media/external/downloads/152" and android says no such file or directory. 

What i want: copy database file in another database file, save/send it to server or locl memory

Comment: If sending to server from local is automated process, then you can save it in your app directory path. For example ```context.getExternalFilesDir("backup");```. So that you can access easily.